# Function that is 1 if input is positive, 0 otherwise

Tags: article-writing

I am trying to write a certain matrix neatly for a paper, but I do not know how I would go about writing what I want formally.

I have two variables, *x* and *y*, which can assume any value. I want to express a matrix *M* whose first diagonal component is 1 if *x* is positive, 0 otherwise. The second diagonal component is 1 if *x* is negative, 0 otherwise. The third diagonal component is 1 if *y* is positive, 0 otherwise. The fourth diagonal component is 1 if *x* is negative, 0 otherwise.
For example:

*x* = 2, *y* = 1 -> diag(*M*) = [1 0 1 0];

*x* = 0, *y* = 1 -> diag(*M*) = [0 0 1 0];

*x* = -3, *y* = -2 -> diag(*M*) = [0 1 0 1];

In code, I would write that as:

diag(*M*) = [*x* > 0; *x* < 0; *y* > 0; *y* < 0];

Basically:

$\begin{equation}
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
x>0 &  & &\\
 & x<0 & &\\
 & & y>0&\\
 & & & y<0
\end{bmatrix}    
\end{equation}
$

And the boolean comparison is automatically converted to a 1 if true and 0 if false.

Would the latter be a good notation for a paper? Or is this only valid in code? I need to write this a lot of times and I want it to be clear what the matrix represent.
Something maybe along the lines of the *sign* function, but that is -1 if the number is negative, and not zero so it does not work.

Basically it is not clear to me how to represent a boolean condition that translates to 1 if valid and 0 otherwise

I know that an alternative would be to write

$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if x > 0}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}$

but that would be too much for the matrix I need to write since it is repeated four times slightly differently.

Cheers

Comment: How about $u[n]$, the unit step function?

Comment: You could write it with an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) (eg $\mathbf 1_{> 0}(x)$ or $\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R^+}(x)$) but as always, it's best to define that notation first.

Comment: I knew there was something else - have a look at [the Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Iverson bracket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) is often used for things like this, where $[P] \equiv\begin{cases} 1 & \text{$P$ is true} \\ 0 & \text{$P$ is false} \end{cases}$

So in this case, you could write $[x > 0]$, $[y > 0]$, etc.

Comment: Exactly was I was looking for, thanks to you both!